# What kind of exercises should I do to build up endurance, speed and agility?

Tags: soccer

I’m a die hard soccer fan and play this game nearly every day. I like to play as a center forward. The problem is I don’t have much speed and agility and my endurance is also not good. So please recommend some good exercises to build up endurance, speed and agility.

Comment: You should be asking a soccer coach.  Typically, with any sport, you perform movements that mimic what you would do while competing.

Comment: I agree with @rrirower you should be asking a soccer coach but can I ask you to clarify how old you are? Another question I have is if you are playing nearly every day then why hasn't your speed, agility and endurance improved? Soccer is a grueling sport especially for a center forward.How long have you been playing "nearly every day"? Has it been a couple months? weeks? Maybe you shouldn't be playing the position you have been playing for a while without improving.

Comment: Starting Strength, v3 is based on general athletic training for field sports.

Comment: starting strength is the most minimalist thing ever. Minimalist training is worse than not training at all since it cause muscle imbalances that can lead to serious injuries and body dysfunctions.

Answer (score 1):

Have coached swimming for 35 years and practicing sprint or quickness drills only maybe three times a week or at least a specific half of a practice session will benefit your desires. One third of a session just focused on each of the needs will do more than just generally working overall skills. Aerobics should be starting point, followed by a third skill sets only and finish with the speed sets last since they require the rest time needed to recover from! If possible stress endurance an entire session and the skills afterward as recovery. Speed is sprinting and more recovery demanding possibly followed by just shooting and passing sets of drills. Endurance could be done as a morning only activity prior to school or work.